# Magento: how to configure cron settings using GUI?

Tags: php, user-interface, magento, cron

It's not a problem to set cron intervals using xml-config file, but it'll be great to have ability to do that using config panel of custom module any time if needed. Friendly GUI instead of "terrible" XML, which could be accessible via FTP.

I have one idea only: catch some event when admin updates configuration of a given module and rewrite that xml-file by custom mechanism, but I don't like this solution. Maybe you know better or/and standard way?

Comment: I've never gone back once I used http://www.cpanel.net/

Comment: It's a good system, but I should create independent module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento usually grabs all the cron data from the XML files you don't seem to be in favor of, but there's no reason you couldn't override it to use some other data model that gets retrieved from the database. Then you could have a simple interface to manage the cron details in the admin.